# Run socket.io with ssl

Tags: javascript, express, socket.io

I'm using `socket.io` with `node.js` over `express` and i'm trying to run my socket over ssl/https

Everything is fine without https but i can't get it work when i try to run it with `https`.

This is my `app.js` file which i use when i write `node app.js` and run my socket

```
Object.size = function(obj) {
    var size = 0, key;
    for (key in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) size++;
    }
    return size;
};
function guid() {
  return s4() + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' +
    s4() + '-' + s4() + s4() + s4();
}

function s4() {
  return Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000)
    .toString(16)
    .substring(1);
}
// This is the main file of our chat app. It initializes a new 
// express.js instance, requires the config and routes files
// and listens on a port. Start the application by running
// 'node app.js' in your terminal
var total = 0;

var usuarios = [];
var soporte = [];

var express = require('express'),
app = express();
Array.prototype.remove = function() {
    var what, a = arguments, L = a.length, ax;
    while (L && this.length) {
        what = a[--L];
        while ((ax = this.indexOf(what)) !== -1) {
            this.splice(ax, 1);
        }
    }
    return this;
};

// This is needed if the app is run on heroku:

var port = process.env.PORT || 8000;

// Initialize a new socket.io object. It is bound to 
// the express app, which allows them to coexist.

var io = require('socket.io').listen(app.listen(port));

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.emit('supports',soporte.length);
    socket.on('load_s',function(data){
        //seguridad.push( socket );
        soporte.push({'socket':socket,'id':socket.id});
        usuarios.forEach(function(item, index, arr){
            console.log(item)
            if(item.atendido == false){
                //socket.emit('lista',{'usuarios':usuarios});
            }
        });
        console.log("Nuevo soporte conectado");

    });
    socket.on('get_supp',function(data){

    });
    socket.on('load_u',function(data){
        var _s = socket;
        usuarios[_s.id] = {'socket' : socket, 'atendido' : false}
        console.log("Usuario en espera"+socket.id);
        //////// Buscar Soporte y asignar /////
        console.log("Soporte disponible "+ soporte.length);
        if(soporte.length == 0){
            console.log("No hay soporte disponible")
            socket.emit('no_supp');
        }else{
            /// PONER EN LISTA PARA SOPORTE
            socket.emit('wait');
            /// ENVIAR NOTIFICACION A SOPORTES
            for (i = 0; i < soporte.length; i++) {
                soporte[i].socket.emit("nuevo_usuario", {'nombre':data.nombre, 'email':data.email, 'id':_s.id, 'question':data.question,'area': data.area})
            }
        }
    });

    socket.on('new_msg',function(data){
        /// get usuario from list
        var usuario = usuarios[data.id].socket
        usuario.emit('new_msg', {'mensaje':data.mensaje,'nombre':data.nombre}); // enviar a usuario
    });
    socket.on('desconectar',function(data){
        var usuario = usuarios[data.id].socket
        usuario.emit('desconectar');
    });
    socket.on('new_msg_u',function(data){
        /// get usuario from list
        _id = socket.id;

        for ( i = 0; i < soporte.length; i++){
            if(soporte[i].id == data.id){
                soporte[i].socket.emit('new_msg', {'mensaje':data.mensaje,'id_usuario':_id}); // enviar a usuario
            }
        }
    });
    socket.on('take_user',function(data){
        /// tomar usuario ////
        console.log("usuario tomado");
        var id_soporte = socket.id // id de soporte
        var id_usuario = data.id // id del usuario
        usuarios[id_usuario].atendido = true // pasar atendido a verdadero
        for (i = 0; i < soporte.length; i++) { /// emitir usuario tomado
            if(soporte[i].id != socket.id){
                soporte[i].socket.emit("usuario_tomado", {'id':id_usuario})
                /// eliminar de la lista
            }
        }
        usuarios[id_usuario].socket.emit('atendido',{'id_soporte':socket.id});
    });
    socket.on('send_chat',function(data){
        if (data.id in departamentos) {
            // send chat , esta conectado   
            console.log('conectado');
            usuarios[data.id].emit("mensaje",{text:data.text});
        }
        else{
            // send push, está desconectado 
            console.log('desconectado');
        }
    });
    socket.on('send_chat_u',function(data){
        if (data.id in soporte) {
            // send chat , esta conectado   
            console.log('conectado');
            soporte[data.id].emit("mensaje",{text:data.text});
        }
        else{
            // send push, está desconectado 
            console.log('desconectado');
        }
    });
    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
        console.log("desconectado");
        soporte.forEach(function(item, index, arr){
            console.log(item.id+" .. "+socket.id+" ... "+index);
            if(item.id == socket.id){
                console.log("coincide");
                delete soporte[index];
                soporte.splice(index, 1);

            }else{
                item.socket.emit('usuario_desconectado',socket.id);
            }
        });
        delete usuarios[socket.id];
    });
});
console.log('Chat running' + port);
```

Then in my js client file i init my chat with:

```
socket = io.connect('https://www.xxxxxxxxx.com.mx:8000', {secure: true});
```

I was reading this docs:

> https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-use-ssltls-with-node-js/

But i don't know how to implement it in `express` (my code example which run correctly without ssl)

I have my `privkey.pem` and `cert.pem` ready to use but as i said before, i don't know how to implement it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, finally i get it work.

```
socket = io.connect('https://www.xxxxx.com.mx:8000', {transports: ['websocket']});
```

And this is my `app.js` code:

```
var port = process.env.PORT || 8000;

// Initialize a new socket.io object. It is bound to 
// the express app, which allows them to coexist.


var fs = require( 'fs' );
var app = require('express')();
var https        = require('https');
var server = https.createServer({
    key: fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/www.xxxxx.com.mx/privkey.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/www.xxxxx.com.mx/cert.pem'),
    //ca: fs.readFileSync('./test_ca.crt'),
    requestCert: false,
    rejectUnauthorized: false
},app);
server.listen(8000);

var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

io.on('connection', function(socket) {

...
```